# How change autoscroll direction to ltr in splide js?

Tags: javascript, splidejs

I use splide js slider, and use autoscroll exstension. But I can't find a solution to change direction from (default: right to left), to (left to right). i try this

```
<script>
    const splide = new Splide( '.splide', {
        type: 'loop',
        drag: false,
        focus: 'center',
        perPage: 5,
        arrows: false,
        pagination: false,
        autoScroll: {
            speed: 3,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            direction: 'ltr',
        },
        breakpoints: {
            1200: {perPage: 3},
            640: {perPage: 2},
        }
    } );

    splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
</script>
```

example link: [enter link description here](https://splidejs.com/extensions/auto-scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, only set a negative value for speed:

```
autoScroll: {
  speed: -3,
  pauseOnHover: false,
}
```